# Why can't I see the session variables set previously?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, session-variables

I have two processes. The first (#1) sets some session variables and also creates a cookie with the session_id in it. The second (#2)reads the cookie and runs this code:

```
session_id($_COOKIE['cookie_session']);
session_start();
```

I stop the code after the session start and I then look with the debugger at the `$_SESSION` (in #2). All I see in the is `_ci_last_regenerate`. My session variables are not in there. Why?

Comment: Why not use the standard PHPSESSID cookie?

Comment: what procedure you follow to set the session? i am asumming you are using codeigniter 3, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to set the session in codeigniter 3 all you have to do is:

```
$this->load->library( 'session' );
$this->session->set_userdata( 'namesession', 'information_on_session');
```